# Random Character Generator Behaving Strange

Tags: java

I'm writing this algorithm that replaces a letter in a name with a random letter at a random location. It does what I need it to do, but after a couple iterations of this algorithm, it starts replacing every letter with 1 letter.

**For example:** *greg
rrer
ttet
dded
yyey
jjej
ffef
hheh
rrer
rrlr
rrwr
rrhr
vvwv
oowo
bbwb
yywy
mmwm
mmtm
llwl
mmwm
mmim
ggig
eeie
eeie
ffif
jjij
jjwj
bbib
ggig
ggbg
kkbk
ggag
ccac
hhah
ccmc
zzaz
llal
eeae
wwaw
wwpw
ddpd
ffpf
yypy
iipi
ffsf
rrsr
ssss
iiii
bbbb
iiii
dddd
xxxx
ssss
llll
uuuu
ssss*

I'm at a loss as to why it starts to do this after functioning properly. Any advice is much appreciated!

```
private static String replaceName() {

            final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            final int alphaNum = alphabet.length();
            String newName = null;

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < (r.nextInt(name.length()) + 1); i++) {

                int replaceCharAt = r.nextInt(name.length());

                newName = name.replace(name.charAt(replaceCharAt), alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphaNum)));
                //System.out.println(newName);

            }

            return newName;

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: To be clear you want to start with "greg" and you want to replace every instance of "g" in greg to another letter? Or you just want to replace one of the "g"s with another letter?

Comment: I want to replace a random letter in the string with a new character. I don't want it to replace every instance of a letter that's in the string. Which now I just realized that .replace replaces every occurrence of the oldChar

Comment: Well, String.replace replaces all instances of a character with they new character, so that probably isn't what you want. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: Also your line: "for (int i = 0; i < (r.nextInt(name.length()) + 1); i++)" runs the for loop for random number of times from between 1 and 26 times. I'm not sure that is what you really want.

Comment: It shouldn't! "name.length()" should only go up until the length of the name. Also is there another method to use besides String.replace that only replaces one character?

Comment: You can use name.replaceFirst() instead. Since you're choosing a random char, the first occurence should be random as well. Not that totally random though as you're more probable to replace from the beginning. You can wrap your string in a StringBuilder() and use replace(start, end, replacement)

Comment: You're not looping until name.length(), you generate a random number up to the length and iterate through that. I don't get why do you need a loop at all, you just want to replace one char. The loop is not useful anyway because you keep assigning new value to newName every time so there's no real effect for the loop tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doenst swap positions, it replaces occurencies of a character by another one.

You will be better by using a char array

```
char[] stringChars = yourString.toCharArray();
```

Replace then by indexes and return a string with

```
String result = new String(stringChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use String.replace(), since that replaces ALL instances of a character. Instead I think you should use StringBuilder.setCharAt() like this:

```
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String name = "greg";        
        StringBuilder newName = new StringBuilder(name);

        Random r = new Random();
        int replaceCharAt = r.nextInt(name.length());
        newName.setCharAt(replaceCharAt, alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));

        System.out.println("HERE: " + newName);
```